# Ultra-minor bug with the JLU furigana extensions

Tags: bug, status-completed, furigana

The furigana extension should not style or otherwise interact with any of the text in the `#hot-network-questions` sidebar, so as to prevent this:

[image: weird floating "x"]

The link should instead read:

> [Undesired spacing before \sqrt[n]​{x}, proper way to fix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225600/undesired-spacing-before-sqrtnx-proper-way-to-fix)

Comment: I've added a fix to https://gist.github.com/cyphr/6536814. As you say though, this is very minor, so I think I shouldn't ask the Stack Exchange people to update the Furigana script until there are more substantial changes.

Comment: The fix was implemented with the [last update](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/1628).