# Furigana engine update for December 2015

Tags: discussion, furigana

It's that time of year again, where the Furigana engine has been starting to show cracks, and there's the feeling it needs to be duly resuscitated.

I've been trying to employ, as much as I reasonably can, a balanced approach in resolving, or mitigating, the following issues in the **(now live)** new version of the Furigana engine:

- > [Do we really need ruby characters all the time?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/do-we-really-need-ruby-characters-all-the-times) and 
  >   [The state of browser support of Furigana, and bottom-aligned Furigana](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/the-state-of-browser-support-of-furigana-and-bottom-aligned-furigana)

  First and foremost, I've tried to put focus on reducing the visual impact of Furigana, and making sure things render consistently across browsers and OSes (whether mobile or desktop). Most of the changes can be seen in [my answer](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1494/796) to the latter question.
- > [直 and 喝: Han unification, and being able to write Japanese on JSE](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/%e7%9b%b4-and-%e5%96%9d-han-unification-and-being-able-to-write-japanese-on-jse)

  With `{{(lang code):text}}` tags, you will be able to insert `<span lang="(lang code)">text</span>`, and use a font for that language (as chosen by the OS).
- > [Fix furigana on the mobile version of our page](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1351/fix-furigana-on-the-mobile-version-of-our-page)

  The Furigana engine should fully be supported in the mobile site.  I'll ask about whether it can be added when asking for the update to be performed.
- > [User Experience: Discovering the Formatting Syntax Documentation](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/user-experience-discovering-the-formatting-syntax-documentation)

  I've added "Furigana/Japanese extension help »" links below the inline editors to make sure people can find the docs.
- > [Encouraging participation from native Japanese speakers: translating posts](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/encouraging-participation-from-native-japanese-speakers-translating-posts)

  I've added basic translation tage: you can add `# Japanese`/`# 日本語`/`# 和訳` and `# English`/`# 英語`/`# 英訳` header tags at the start of lines to allow for tabbed translations.

  This is simplified a lot from what I previously coded to try to keep things simple.  I might extend this if it gets used.  If it doesn't and it needs to be removed, the answers will be backwards reversible (as they're just standard headings).
- > [Struckthrough Japanese text doesn't get wrapped in a lang="ja" span](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/struckthrough-japanese-text-doesnt-get-wrapped-in-a-lang-ja-span) and [Ultra-minor bug with the JLU furigana extensions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/ultra-minor-bug-with-the-jlu-furigana-extensions)

  Have been fixed.

---

<s>I might wait for a week or two before asking for an update to check everything's stable, but if you'd like, you can try the new engine on Chrome or Firefox) in the meantime by:</s>

1. Using adblock plus [[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb)/[Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)] to block `//sstatic.net/js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js?v=9` (the current version used on JLSE)
2. Installing [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)(FF)/[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)(Chrome)
3. Then going to http://gist.github.com/cyphr/6536814, and clicking "Raw" in the top right.

---

Please let me know if there's any issues I've missed/anything you think should be changed etc.

Comment: Presents, yay!!

Comment: I'm using it and I like it a lot! :-)  I made the furigana little and turned on maximum squishing, and I feel like it doesn't interfere with the regular text much anymore.

Comment: What do you think about making the mouseover text optional in the *Japanese settings* dialogue?  (I like the mouseover personally, though.)

Comment: @snailboat I've added such an option to the dialog, also added a fast fade-in effect and made the popups go [over the top of the ruby](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BcoL7.png) text rather than where the mouse cursor is...I can't explain why, but the popups didn't quite seem right to me before these changes.

Comment: To be honest, I myself previously wasn't really using the Furigana engine, and was preferring just markup as I found it easier to read...but I quite like the new rendering too.

Comment: (note: Since my last comment, I've changed the popups to be a "unified" white background with a border, which I think is easier to read/identify: http://i.stack.imgur.com/A88wb.png)

Comment: Testing: [漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字]{ああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああ}

Answer (score 3):

Minor issues:

1. Very wide furigana causes problems in comments, as in [this test comment](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/furigana-engine-update-for-december-2015#comment3605_1495).

   Here's what I typed in to make that comment (plus a zero-width space to prevent it from rendering):

   > Testing: [漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字]​{ああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああああ}

   And here's how it renders:

   > [image: broken layout screenshot]

   This doesn't happen without the furigana engine.  If I write 漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢字漢 without any furigana markup, it wraps properly.

   ---
2. I'd like to disable the new mouseover when the furigana consists of [emphasis dots](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%8F%E7%82%B9), like in the following:

   > 文字を[強調]{﹅・﹅}する

   This form of emphasis is useful for Japanese and the furigana engine gives us an easy way to do it, and now that we have furigana on mobile I think I might like to use it a little bit more often.  But it looks weird when we mouseover:

   > [image: emphasis dots screen shot]

   Since the mouseover is already disabled for pitch accent (it doesn't show up for [やじろべえ]{LHHLL}), maybe we could add one more special case? :-)  If we do this, I think we would want to add a special case for at least `◦`, `﹆` and `﹅`.

   ---

Neither of these is likely to come up very often.

Comment: Noted - there are a couple of things I'd like to change (so far the line-height issues for pad, making it so {{(lang):text}} tags can work in headings, fixing a bug which makes Japanese always first in translations, and other things which I didn't previously notice).  Fortunately I think none of these are show-stopping, so I might leave it for the next few weeks, and update along with any other issues people report in the meantime.

Comment: I think emphasis dots could also be made to span each kanji, so that you can type `﹅﹅` rather than `﹅・﹅ ` with the middle dot each time for the Furigana.

Comment: @cypher Oh, I'd like that! :-)

Comment: The script has now been updated with the emphasis dot changes. I've also made Kanji >30 chars or Furigana >50 chars output as text to work around that issue for now.  Is there a good reason to allow Furigana longer than that?  While probably possible, it would be very difficult to make Furigana wrap with the current implementation.

Comment: Testing: [強調]{﹅﹅}

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the update! It's working very well in my iPhone Safari too. However, I found a tiny problem in seemingly limited environments:

[image]

It seems the paragraph with `{{​pad}}` has oversized characters when ruby attached, which doesn't on my PC Firefox.

**PS**
Is there any possibility the furigana feature gets imported to official mobile app?

Comment: Thanks for reporting+sorry for getting back to you late, I've been away for a few days. The `{{​pad}}` issue should (hopefully) be largely fixed now on the (currently unreleased) version on GitHub.

Comment: As for the second query abut the official mobile app(s), I think it's extremely unlikely I'd be able to do that on either Android or iPhone.  SE has said they're reluctant to fully open source the Android app because of the need to hide code about their "secret" endpoints (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230458), and it would be very unlikely I could add the Furigana engine to the apps/fix any issues as they arise as a result.